# how to include blade file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am developing Laravel application and I need add comment form to My each task file regarding to each project.
this is comments/form.blade.php

```
 <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.comments.create', $project->id) }}">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('comments') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <textarea name="comments" class="form-control" style="width:80%;" id="comment" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
            @if ($errors->has('comments'))
                <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('comments') }}</span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Comment</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </form>
```

I am going to include this form file to show.blade.php file in tasks folder in view file.
this is show.blade.php

```
<h2>{{ $tasks->project->project_name }}</h2>
<hr>

{{$tasks->task_name}}
<hr>

{!!$tasks->body!!}

<hr>

@include('comments.form')
```

commentController.php

```
 public function postNewComment(Request $request, $id, Comment $comment)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'comments'     => 'required|min:5',
        ]);

       $comment->comments       = $request->input('comments');
       $comment->project_id     = $id;
       $comment->user_id        = Auth::user()->id;
       $comment->save();

       return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Comment posted successfully');
    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/comments', [
    'uses' => 'CommentsController@postNewComment',
    'as'   => 'projects.comments.create',
    'middleware' => ['auth']
]);
```

but finally got this error massage

```
Undefined variable: project (View: C:\Users\Nalaka\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\comments\form.blade.php)
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: You must have `$project` before include `form.blade`

Comment: try to change `$project->id` to `$tasks->project->id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `$project` anywhere but you have `$tasks` from which you are getting project name already in `show.blade.php` so if you have project id also there in `$tasks->project` data then you can use this variable in view change `form` tag in  **comments/form.blade.php** as below:

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.comments.create', $tasks->project->id) }}">
```

Comment: I have another question if I need save comments via each tasks in the project may I need tasks column in the comment table?

Comment: Yes you need to give reference of task table in comment table

Comment: ok now I can display comment box in My show.blade.php file but when I post new comment its generated new error massage like this **Class App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController does not exist**

Comment: typo here `CommentsController` needs to be `CommentController` in **routes.php**

Comment: now generated **Class App\Http\Controllers\CommentController does not exist**

Comment: Your controller name must start with uppercase letter `commentController.php` should be `CommentController.php` also controller class name should be `CommentController`